# Is there any way to make the text scroll faster?

Tags: solatorobo-red-the-hunter

In Solatorobo:Red the Hunter, I find the text scrolls slower than I would like.

I know that the manual says that I can press <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to automatically advance the text, but that skips over things, and I don't want to miss what people are saying. I just want them to say it faster.

Is this an option? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: *C'est pas vrai!* Isn't it **R** + **A**? Technically this advances the text really fast, but there's no way to up make them talk faster w/o auto advancing to the next dialog.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. And I wouldn't say it advances really fast - it just skips.

Comment: i cant remember the exact other question but i'm seeming to remember seeing this asked in the past, and the answer was in short: no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can and it's so obvious that it's possible you might be doing it already - **hold <kbd>A</kbd>**. Just to be certain, I started up my copy and tested several combinations of input to come up with this answer. According to the game manual's control section (page 12 in my copy), it says:

> ### A Button
>
> Confirm selections/advance on-screen messages.

This doesn't overtly answer your question as text dialogs ask you to press <kbd>A</kbd> to advance to the next screen of text, in fitting with what the manual describes. However, it should be noted that **holding <kbd>A</kbd> while text fills the dialog makes the text fill the dialog somewhat faster** and this can also be considered advancing on-screen messages. The increase in text speed offered by holding <kbd>A</kbd> is not dramatically significant so you may not notice it at first, but to verify that there is a difference, all you need to do is let a dialog fill with text without holding <kbd>A</kbd> and it should be clear. Even holding <kbd>A</kbd> part way through a dialog filling with text is a sufficient demonstration of the difference.

On the same page of the manual, it also says:

> - During a conversation, hold down the R button and A button simultaneously to have the conversation automatically advance.

As noted in the manual <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> skips over text dialogs, often before the text is even near finished being printed to the screen as you have noted.

To have speed and control of a text dialog, all you need to do is **hold <kbd>A</kbd> all the time in text dialogs, and when you've finished reading the current screen of text, tap (but do not hold) <kbd>R</kbd> to advance the dialog to the next screen**.